# Preserve time spacing ratio of gaps in Highstock charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highstock charts, any gap will always have the same width (it seems the width of the smallest distance between points) regardless of the time interval of the gap, resulting in narrowing of the time/x axis, while this doesn't happen in the "navigation" series.

[image: Example of gap]

Is there any easy way to make the chart preserve the spacing of the gap according to its duration, as it already happens in the navigation bar (thus keeping the x axis without narrowing)?

Comment: `gapSize` may be what you need? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.gapSize

Comment: Normal Highstock chart is using ordinal xAxis. You can try disabling it by setting xAxis.ordinal to false http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński That's it! Thank you very much, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @jlbriggs I'm already using `gapSize` as it is necessary for showing the gaps (otherwise the endpoints of the gaps are linked with a line as well), but still the gaps don't take the intended space according to their length in time. The problem was the default setting of the x axis to "ordinal" as GrzegorzBlachliński pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Highstock chart is using ordinal xAxis by default.

> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart regardless of the actual time or x distance between them. This means that missing data for nights or weekends will not take up space in the chart. Defaults to true.

You can try disabling this parameter by setting xAxis.ordinal to false http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

```
        xAxis: {
            ordinal: false
        },
```